# Which way of formulating a proposition in an article is better?

Tags: proof-writing

Which of the following ways is preferable to formulate a proposition including much uncommon notation?
1)  [half-page description of the notation in style "Consider projections of similar convex polyhedrons to a plane, orthogonal to S. Define *section* as..., sizes *x* of section as..., *3D size a* as..., orientation $\Theta$ as.... Define the following dimensional parameters of such projection: $x_{i,j}$, $y_{i,j}$, where i is ... and j is..., $k_{i,j}=x_{i,j}/a$, $p_{i,j}=y_{i,j}/ \sum_{i,j} y_{i,j}$... as shown in figure 1. Let $f_A(a)$ be...., $F_A(a)$ be ..."]
*Proposition 1. The probability density function for sizes of section of similar convex polyhedrons equals  $h_X x)| \Theta$ = an expression including $\sum_{i,j} F_A (x, k_{i,j})$, $p_{i,j}$,  where all the notation is as defined over.*
Proof <...>

2)[A description only of the heaviest notation with reference to the  figure 1.]
*Proposition 1. The probability density function for sizes of section of similar convex polyhedrons, having true 3D size distribution density $f_A (a)$ equals

 $h_X x)| \Theta$ = an expression including $\sum_{i,j} F_A (x, k_{i,j})$, $p_{i,j}$, where $F_A(x)$ is a cumulative distribution function for A and the dimensional parameters $k_{i,j}$, $p_{i,j}$ are as defined over.*
Proof <...>

3)*Proposition 1. Let [half-page description in the same style as in "1)" and reference to figure 1.] Then $h_X x)| \Theta$ = an expression including $\sum_{i,j} F_A (x, k_{i,j})$, $p_{i,j}$*
Proof <...>

4) Let [half-page description in the same style as in "1)" and reference to figure 1].
  Then [half-page proof].
 Consequently,
*Proposition 1. The probability density function for sizes of section of similar convex polyhedrons equals

$h_X x)| \Theta$ = an expression including $\sum_{i,j} F_A (x, k_{i,j})$, $p_{i,j}$*

5) Perhaps there are much better ways to express such things? I would appreciate any suggestions or references how to write it clearly.

Comment: This is very opinion-based, but I suggest that the statement itself, the text in the proposition, is formulated in a brief way. This means that 1. is the best version, but I would skip the sentence "where all the notation is as defined over." because it's rather redundant. 
I really dislike version 4 because you don't know as reader where the steps in the proof are supposed to lead you.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I will do as you suggest.